# DateBridge for LocalDate in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, date, search, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate search 11.5.2.Final in a SpringBoot app.

I'm trying to search for the field `createdAt` of the entity `Book`.

when I run it, the application exits with an exception like

```java
Unable to create bean for LocalDateBridge
```

I get the same kind of Exception for fields of type `Long` also

my entity looks like this

```java
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id 
    private Long id;


    @Field
    @DateBridge(resolution=Resolution.DAY)
    private LocalDate createdAt;

    // Other fields and setters & getters
}
```

Here is the Full stack trace

```java
2019-08-05 13:42:57.789  WARN 14452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] g.e.SimpleDataFetcherExceptionHandler    : Exception while fetching data (/Books) : Exception while calling bridge#objectToString
    entity class: com.app.model.Book
    entity property path: createdAt
    field bridge: TwoWayString2FieldBridgeAdaptor [stringBridge=org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.time.impl.LocalDateBridge@4ef6ee21]

org.hibernate.search.bridge.BridgeException: Exception while calling bridge#objectToString
    entity class: com.app.model.Book
    entity property path: createdAt
    field bridge: TwoWayString2FieldBridgeAdaptor [stringBridge=org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.time.impl.LocalDateTimeBridge@4ef6ee21]
    at org.hibernate.search.bridge.util.impl.ContextualExceptionBridgeHelper.buildBridgeException(ContextualExceptionBridgeHelper.java:104) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.bridge.util.impl.ContextualExceptionBridgeHelper$TwoWayConversionContextImpl.objectToString(ContextualExceptionBridgeHelper.java:161) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.objectToString(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:274) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.objectToString(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:1066) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.objectToString(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:1049) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.FieldContext.objectToString(FieldContext.java:75) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.buildSearchTerm(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:149) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.createQuery(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:113) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.createQuery(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:81) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at io.leangen.graphql.metadata.execution.SingletonMethodInvoker.execute(SingletonMethodInvoker.java:21) ~[spqr-0.9.9.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.metadata.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:100) ~[spqr-0.9.9.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.execution.OperationExecutor.lambda$execute$1(OperationExecutor.java:93) ~[spqr-0.9.9.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.execution.OperationExecutor$$Lambda$1440/231233146.aroundInvoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.execution.OperationExecutor.execute(OperationExecutor.java:98) ~[spqr-0.9.9.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.execution.OperationExecutor.execute(OperationExecutor.java:94) ~[spqr-0.9.9.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.execution.OperationExecutor.execute(OperationExecutor.java:59) ~[spqr-0.9.9.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.generator.OperationMapper$$Lambda$1152/966240044.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.fetchField(ExecutionStrategy.java:261) [graphql-java-11.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.resolveFieldWithInfo(ExecutionStrategy.java:202) [graphql-java-11.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.execution.AsyncExecutionStrategy.execute(AsyncExecutionStrategy.java:70) [graphql-java-11.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.execution.Execution.executeOperation(Execution.java:159) [graphql-java-11.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.execution.Execution.execute(Execution.java:101) [graphql-java-11.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.GraphQL.execute(GraphQL.java:573) [graphql-java-11.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.GraphQL.parseValidateAndExecute(GraphQL.java:515) [graphql-java-11.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.GraphQL.executeAsync(GraphQL.java:489) [graphql-java-11.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.GraphQL.execute(GraphQL.java:420) [graphql-java-11.0.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.web.servlet.DefaultGraphQLExecutor.execute(DefaultGraphQLExecutor.java:23) [graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure-0.0.4.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.web.servlet.DefaultGraphQLExecutor.execute(DefaultGraphQLExecutor.java:11) [graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure-0.0.4.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.web.GraphQLController.executeJsonPost(GraphQLController.java:42) [graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure-0.0.4.jar:na]
    at io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.web.GraphQLController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$db77e769.invoke(<generated>) [graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure-0.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76) [javamelody-core-1.77.0.jar:1.77.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.web.servlet.DefaultGraphQLController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b8cd271.executeJsonPost(<generated>) [graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure-0.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor
    at org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.time.impl.TemporalAccessorStringBridge.objectToString(TemporalAccessorStringBridge.java:42) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.bridge.util.impl.TwoWayString2FieldBridgeAdaptor.objectToString(TwoWayString2FieldBridgeAdaptor.java:33) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.bridge.util.impl.ContextualExceptionBridgeHelper$TwoWayConversionContextImpl.objectToString(ContextualExceptionBridgeHelper.java:158) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.11.2.Final.jar:5.11.2.Final]
    ... 151 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of your DAO class, where you are using this entity with a querybuilder. Seems like you are passing a String instead of Localdate to query builder?

Comment: I moved this snipet out of my code base to test the indexing. and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: What code did you move out? Also, is there a new exception after removing the said code. In any case can you update your question with what you tried?

Comment: @bidishamukherjee this snipet is running in a separate project ( i moved it out of my main project to test if the bridge thingy is working)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `@DateBridge(resolution=Resolution.DAY)`: it's not useful in your case since the resolution of a local date is already the day.

The problem was probably caused by explicit resolution not being supported for `java.time` types, but only for legacy `java.util.Date`/`java.util.Calendar` types (where it may actually be useful).

If this doesn't solve the problem, please paste the complete stack trace in your question.

Comment: still the same exception

Answer (score 0):

According to your stack trace, you are passing a `String` object to the query builder, whereas a `LocalDate` object is expected, since your field is of type `LocalDate`.
Parse the user-provided string to a `LocalDate`, then pass that object to the query builder.

Comment: It's the  value that i get from the database, and the field `createdAt` is of type `LocalDate` in my database

Comment: How exactly do you get it from the database? There's no such thing as a LocalDate in a relational database, so depending on how your property is mapped to the database, it's perfectly possible that you're getting a string from a native query, for example. What I'm interested in is the type of the value you pass to `.matching(...)` method in the query DSL.

Comment: its typed as Date in a postgres database 
`created_at DATE`

Comment: What matters is the type of the Java object you pass to `.matching(...)`. It could be `String`, `LocalDate`, or even `Long` for all I know. Hibernate Search expects a `LocalDate`.

Comment: Per my understanding the default LocalDateBridge should convert the value of type `DATE` from the database to a java `LocalDate`,